# Como reiniciar valores en base a otras propiedades de un json? en javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ok, yo quiero reiniciar las propiedades ref y order que vienen en mi json.

Esta es mi función donde recorro el array de objetos

```
async SaveReferences(data: Array<Dataconf>) {
        console.log("array", data)
        let refs = 1;
        let orderField = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
            try {
                let res = await this.referenceService.createReference({
                    service: data[i].service,
                    name: `ref${i++}`,
                    label: data[i].ref,
                    longitud: 0,
                    order: orderField++
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

y cuando llega a la base de datos....

```
service | name   | label | longitud | order | id
  1     | Rodrigo| ref1  |    0     |  1    | 1
  1     | ECHALE | ref2  |    0     |  2    | 2
  1     | ARI    | ref3  |    0     |  3    | 3
  2     | WADIS  | ref4  |    0     |  4    | 4
  2     |  QAZS  | ref5  |    0     |  5    | 5
  3     |  FRVGT | ref6  |    0     |  6    | 6
```

O sea, pero yo necesito reiniciar el campo de order del 0 al 2, como máximo cada 2 registros a partir del 0 y se reiniciar según el valor del campo "service", o bueno, si se puede hacer de forma directa cada 2 registros, como se podria lograr?

Como quisiera, que llegará a la BASE de datos...

```
service | name   | label | longitud | order | id
  1     | Rodrigo| ref1  |    0     |  0    | 1
  1     | ECHALE | ref2  |    0     |  1    | 2
  1     | ARI    | ref3  |    0     |  2    | 3
  2     | WADIS  | ref1  |    0     |  0    | 4
  3     |  QAZS  | ref1  |    0     |  0    | 5
  3     |  FRVGT | ref2  |    0     |  1    | 6
```

Saludos cordiales y agradecidos con sus comentarios.

Comment: podrias indicar como llega actualmente vs como la quieres? no se entiende bien lo que pides

Comment: edite la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Podrías intentar esto:

```
async SaveReferences(data: Array<Dataconf>) {
    console.log("array", data)
    let refs = 1;
    let orderField = 0;
    let helper = data[0].service;

    for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].service != helper){
            helper = data[i].service;
            orderField = 0;
        }
        try {
            let res = await this.referenceService.createReference({
                service: data[i].service,
                name: `ref${i++}`,
                label: data[i].ref,
                longitud: 0,
                order: orderField
            });
            orderField++:
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: edite la pregunta hahaha

Comment: Ok, yo igual edité mi respuesta. Puedes Intentar a ver que tal.